# How to create multiple flows with various data using Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch to deal with whole records in one database.
What I should do with these datas basically depends on each record.
There can be three status with each record, for example A / B / C.

I want sort all records into these thress status.
For example, 
 A   - record1, record2, record3
 B   - record4, record5, record 6
 c   - record7, record8, record9

then I'd like to create step flow(or job flow? i dont know exactly..) based on these three status.
( Step 'aStep' would deal with A kinds of records, 'bStep' would deal with B kinds of records... and so forth)

How can I do this with Spring Batch?
I've already read a lot on spring flow, decisions which are based on ExitStatus or BatchStatus but cannot find any ways to do exactly what I wanna do.

Please help me if you knows about how to do this.

Comment: Can the different statuses be processed in parallel?

Comment: @Michael i dont really know whether i can or not. i just wonder if there is some way to do but I could find nothing yet

Comment: do you really need a separate step/flow for each type of record? did you try it with just a reader selecting all records (ordered by type) and different processing in processor/writer per record type? you could even parallelize it using a partitioned step, where each partition utilises only one type of record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in **processor level** but not in step level.

```
  @Component
@Scope(value = "step")
public class AbcItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<AbcInfo, AbcInfo> {
    @Override
    public AbcInfo process(AbcInfo abcInfo) throws Exception {

        if (abcInfo.getRecordType().equals("H") || abcInfo.getRecordType().equals("T"))
            return null;//do your changes as you want to do with record based on condition
        else {
            abcInfo.setIdBatch(idBatch);
            abcInfo.setTmStamp(new Date(timeInMillis));
            return abcInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

OR if you are insisted to do it **step level** then you can do it by writing your own decider like following by passing custom status

```
public class StepFlowController implements JobExecutionDecider{

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        FlowExecutionStatus status = null;
        try {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();

            Object validationStatus = executionContext.get("VALIDATESTATUS");
            if (!Utils.isNullOrEmpty(validationStatus)) {
                if (validationStatus.equals("HEADERFAIL")) {
                    status = new FlowExecutionStatus("HEADER");;
                } else if (validationStatus.equals("TAILERFAIL")) {
                    status = new FlowExecutionStatus("TRAILER");
                } else if (validationStatus.equals("DATACOUNTFAIL")) {
                    status = new FlowExecutionStatus("DATA");
                }else {
                    status = new FlowExecutionStatus("COMPLETE");
                }
            }else {
                status = new FlowExecutionStatus("COMPLETE");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

}
```

In the configuration file you can put a decider like below

```
    <decision id="validationDecision" decider="validationDecider">
                <next on="HEADER" to="HeaderStep" />
                <next on="TRAILER" to="TrailerStep" />
                <next on="DATE" to="DataStep" />
                <next on="FAILED" to="FailStep" />
                <next on="COMPLETE" to="CompleteStep" />
            </decision>
```